# C# errors running javascript and getting cell content

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make a graph with the content in a GridView, and now I have this codes:

```
string js0 = @"var data = {}; CarregarGrafico(data);";
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Graph0L", js0, true);

var i = 0;
foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
{
  string periodo = "" + row.Cells[0].Text + "/" + row.Cells[1].Text + "";
  string prevReceb = row.Cells[6].Text.ToString();
  string totalReceb = row.Cells[10].Text.ToString();
  string js1 = @"myBarChart.addData([{1}, {2}], '{0}');";
  js1 = js1.Replace("{0}", periodo).Replace("{1}", prevReceb).Replace("{2}", totalReceb);
  ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "Graph1L", js1, true);
  i++;
  if (i >= 10) break;
}
```

But I'm dealing with some problems:

- Script aren't appearing at the page
- I can't get the prevReceb and totalReceb values because it was in a `<span>` tag. How can I use only text into span of the cell?

Please, help me, thanks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: The call to RegisterStartupScript is within the loop; Are you looking to create 1 graph for the grid or 1 graph for each row of the grid?

Comment: Hello, thanks for support. HashPsi, the anwser is no, because the "myBarChart.addData([{1}, {2}], '{0}');" add a data to a graph that is generated with "CarregarGrafico(data);" at the first line.

Comment: The thinks is: the script aren't appearing at the ASP.NET page.